# I think GIMP has glitched out, I can't remove this grid

Tags: gimp, grids, bug

I had to reinstall windows 10 recently after a computer upgrade and after adding GIMP I noticed it has this grid constantly active, even if I put new layers over it.

[image]

I genuinely do not know how to remove it. I've gone into the settings and this option *should* have removed it but even after restarting it does nothing and I'm at a loss as what to do now.
[image]
Should I just uninstall and reinstall, then hope for the best?

Answer (score 1):

This is the ["grid"](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-grid-and-guides.html#gimp-concepts-image-grid).

- It can take several forms: continuous line as in OP, dots, cross hairs, dashed lines (see `Image > Configure grid`).
- Its visibility can be toggled at any time with `View > Show grid`.
- Its effect can be switched on and off with `View > Snap to grid`
- It can be enabled/disabled by default in the preferences (two places, one for normal and one for full-screen display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somebody on the discord spotted what the issue was. I switched off the fullscreen mode but not the windows mode *(which was right above it)*

Comment: Don't forget to choose your own answer as best.